# Twilio: Can a moderator mute specific participants in a conference call?

Tags: twilio

I can use the Twilio JavaScript API to have a participant mute/unmute themselves, but I'm looking for a moderator to be able to mute specific participants, whether they dial in by phone or by clicking to call.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You could build a UI that lets a "moderator" see all of the connected conference participants by using the [Participants resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant) in the REST API.

You can POST to a specific participant to mute them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome-- exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As a bonus feature, is there any way a moderator could see which participant was making noise?  This would be useful when one participant has tremendous background noise but you can't tell which one.

Comment: Sorry.  There is no way to get sound levels from participants.

Comment: Hi @Devin Rader, I've got another Twilio question here that slipped through the cracks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666495/twilio-start-stop-recording-mid-call

Answer (score 1):

it would seem this would have your answer:
http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/moderated-conference

Right below the top tells you to call a noun in     {conference} to be able to mute a specific member.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems it's just for the participants to be able to mute themselves, no?  I'm looking for a way for a moderator to mute a participant.