# Twilio: Start/Stop Recording Mid-Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Two related questions on this topic:

1. Can a moderator of a conference call start or stop recording after the call begins?  Can they do this multiple times, and if so, would that add to the recording, overwrite the recording, or start a new one?
2. If you use the same conference room ID two days in a row, can you add to the recording from Day 1 rather than creating a new recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is no way to start/stop a recording of a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) call through the Record attribute.  You might be able to do this by dialing in Twilio as a participant.

There is also no way to modify an existing recording.  You would have to download the WAV/MP3 and stitch them together yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you specify just a bit more by what you mean by this please: "You might be able to do this by dialing in Twilio as a participant."

Comment: Read more details in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211816/twilio-recording-pause-and-resume/34903288