# Twilio Recording: Pause and Resume

Tags: twilio, voice-recording

I believe the answer is no, but does Twilio provide ability to pause/resume a recording? Use case is recording a call, but pausing recording when collecting sensitive information. From the REST documentation, it doesn't appear to be a supported capability. Thought someone might have found some options for this requirement.

Comment: That's a really good question. It might be worth reaching out to help@twilio.com to see if anyone else has discussed this with us.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible, though it's not wholly obvious how from the documentation.

You can modify call state using the REST API, as per https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state , and we basically use it to tell the call to re-dial to the same agent (presumably this is a call centre?) but with no-record, and then again with record re-activated once we're done.

You end up with two separate recordings for the call, which in our case we download, stitch together, and store back to our storage platform.

Edit:

Having discussed this issue with Twilio support, there's another possibility which allows you to just have a single recording.

Instead of dialling the two ends of the call together, you instead put them both into a conference that's recorded when you initially connect the call.  When you want to pause it, using the REST API, you add a new "hold" leg into the conference, then move the two real ends of the call onto a new conference that isn't recorded.  When you're done, you move them back again and it's "unpaused".  You then only have one recording from the original conference.

None of these is ideal, and apparently they are working on a proper support setup for this (fairly obvious!) requirement, but this should solve it for now.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer, I'm trying to figure out this part "add a new "hold" leg into the conference", how do you do this thru API? Thanks

Comment: Hmm it's a good question and one I never got to the bottom of I'm afraid - Twilio support had suggested it and I didn't think about it that carefully, but it's quite hard to just make it "dial in" to a conference from nowhere..!

We went with the first option, which works well _if you're using the twilio web client_, or you've got call centre on auto-answer.  Otherwise the call drops and it rings again which isn't brilliant.

Comment: Look what Twilio replied: _"The 'statusCallbackEvent' attribute allows you to specify which conference state changes should generate a webhook to the URL specified in the 'statusCallback' attribute. The available values are start, end, join, leave, mute, and hold. To specify multiple values separate them with a space. Events are set by the first Participant to join the conference, subsequent statusCallbackEvents will be ignored. The events are fired on the following state changes. The statusCallbackEvent attribute is the leg that the hold gets added to."_

Comment: Any updates regarding this? I went through their documentation and still cannot find anything related to this. Its been a year since this question was asked first, surely they have added a feature to achieve this by now?

Answer (score 1):

The Recording Pause & Resume feature is now supported in the Twilio API. Here's a link that gets you started:

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010199074-Getting-Started-with-Call-Recording-Controls#pause_resume