# Twilio Recording after call initiated

Tags: rest, twilio, record, twilio-twiml

I'm currently using the Twilio API in order to implement a call-recording feature for my app. I'm wondering whether it is possible to accomplish the following scenario.

1. Person A calls Person B, connection between the two is established
2. Person A would like to start recording the phone call and pushes a recording button
3. Call ends, Person A receives recording

I have tried the following:

1. Connect the two users so that they can talk to each other (Successful)
2. Use the REST API to modify the live call and put the TwiML record verb.(ref https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#example-1)

Been stuck on step 2, whenever I try to redirect at all it just disconnects the call. Is there a proper way to inject TwiML messages while the call is going on using the rest API?

Comment: What language are you using. There are ways to do this directly via the language library or via contacting the server via curl to make the changes and known the language will help someone provide a correct response.

Comment: I am using Node.js. My attempt at modifying a live call have been similar to the examples Twilio provides.

Comment: Can you provide your JavaScript and TWilM code

Comment: Read more details in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211816/twilio-recording-pause-and-resume/34903288