# Use Record and Dial together in Twilio API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio to create call tracking phone numbers that redirect to another number using the Dial verb. I am also recording these calls. Here is an example of my TWIML

```
<Response><Dial record="true" action="http://example.com/PostCall">555-555-5555</Dial></Response>
```

I want to be able to terminate the call recording but not the call using something like the Record verb's finishOnKey option. Is this possible?

The reason is, a call comes in to a call center and is transferred to a lawyer. I want to record the call center part of the call but not the attorney/client part of the call. If pressing # during the call could stop the recording but keep the call active it would solve my problem.

- Is there a way to stop recording without terminating the call?
- Can the record verb be used in conjunction with the dial verb?

Answer (score 1):

The `<Record>` TwiML verb is best if you want to record one person talking. I'm assuming you want to record both parties connected via `<Dial>` in the call center so you would rely on the *record* attribute as you have above.

Read the [FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-record-a-phone-call-with-twilio) for the full breakdown on the difference in recording settings.

> Is there a way to stop recording without terminating the call?

Depending on the flow of your call center you might [modify the live call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) via the REST API and redirect the call to new TwiML where you set recording to "false".

```
call = client.calls.update("CALL_SID", url="https://example.com/no-record.xml",
    method="POST")
```

Alternatively, you could add Twilio itself as a 3rd call leg in a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) call, and let it handle recording. This way you can use the REST API to modify that leg without disrupting the primary 2 callers, including stopping recording of the call midway through while the other 2 callers are still live.

Comment: The first option sounds good but doesn't quite work. Using RedirectCall with this XML just terminates the existing call and calls the person back. I will move on to the conference option and see how that goes.

Comment: It seems you cannot stop a recording in a conference mid call per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666495/twilio-start-stop-recording-mid-call

Comment: Correct, but the answer goes on to say you might be able to do so by dialing Twilio in as a participant that would essentially be there for the call center portion of the call and then drops leaving the caller and the lawyer on the line with no recording.