# How to mute conference in twilio when video is playing on moderator screen where moderator screen shared with participants?

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio(https://twilio.com) in my app(web app) for audio conferencing. Where moderator can share his/her screen with participants while conferencing. But I am facing problem when video is play.

Actually I want to mute conference when video is playing. Is there any way to do that?

Also I didn't get conference-start event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio: Can a moderator mute specific participants in a conference call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637406/twilio-can-a-moderator-mute-specific-participants-in-a-conference-call)

Comment: it is totally a different question